# Prove or disprove: $f$ Is Uniformly continuous

Tags: calculus

We have function $f$, Uniformly continuous on $[0, ∞]$.
We also know $f$ Is strictyl monotonically increasing.

Prove or disprove:
There exists $a > 0$ such that $1/f$ Is Uniformly continuous on $[a, ∞]$.

I have tried to look for a counter example, I could not find any.
It does seem true to me, But I don't know how to prove it. The only thing I can know for sure Is that $1/f$ Will be continuous on $[a, ∞]$ for some $a>0$.

Comment: If $f\equiv 0$ then $\frac 1 f$ is not even defined.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy $f$  Is monotonically increasing.

Comment: Do you mean *strictly* monotonically increasing ?

Comment: @SolubleFish Yes, Edited.

Comment: $f(x) = -1/x^2$ is a counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let :
$$\forall x\in [0,+\infty), f(x) = -\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

Then, $f$ is strictly increasing, uniformly continuous, but $x\mapsto 1/f(x) = -1-
x^2$ is not uniformly continuous on any interval $[a,+\infty)$.